# Not able to access delegate method from presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, delegates

Delegate declaration

```
// FolderListViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Folder.h"

@protocol FolderSelectionDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)setFolder:(Folder *)folder;

@end

@interface FolderListViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<FolderSelectionDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)showDashboard:(id)sender;

@end
```

Delegate is called from didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
// FolderListViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.delegate setFolder:dataSource[indexPath.row]];
}
```

The VC that should be receiving the message

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FolderListViewController.h"
#import "Folder.h"

@interface ProjectListViewController : UITableViewController <FolderSelectionDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,retain)UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorObject;
@property (nonatomic, copy)Folder *folder;


-(void)loadProjects:(Folder*)folder;

@end
```

Action that presents the VC

```
- (void)foldersButtonTapped {
    UINavigationController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FolderListNavController"];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Delegate method implementation

```
- (void)setFolder:(Folder *)folder {
    _folder = folder;
    [self loadProjects:folder];
}
```

I have read through multiple threads on here and haven't had any luck.  At first, I didn't have the reference to ProjectListVC setup when presenting the FolderListVC (ie, vc.delegate = self).  That doesn't seem to be the problem here though.  I am working on an app that was built for iPad and scaling it to work across all devices.  The implementation as it is here works (it's setup as a split view controller).  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It looks to me that you are setting the `UINavigationController`'s delegate instead of your delegate. You need to set your delegate on a `FolderListViewController` instance. You can also rename your delegate property to something like `folderSelectionDelegate` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much - this pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that UINavigationcontroller is creating problem as it is not setting the FolderListViewController delegate . Can You try like this.

```
 FolderListViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FolderListViewController"];

    vc.delegate=self; // protocol listener
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you!  Ended up implementing it this way so I could still present the view controller and maintain a nav bar at the top:

`FolderListViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FolderListPhone"];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

vc.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Nice :) .. Solved both the issue